# To hide edit button when add more than 7 tabcontroller?

Tags: iphone

I added  more than 7 view controllers to the tab bar controller, it shows
more at the end, when I click "more" , it shows remaining, but edit button is available at
the right corner of iPhone screen, I want to disable, hide it?

Answer (score 0):

The Edit button is the way that you can allow the user to rearrange which buttons are in the tabs on the main page.  Are you sure you want to keep the user from rearranging?

If you *do* want to prevent rearranging, the thing to do is something like this:

tabBar.customizableViewControllers = nil;

If you don't do that step, the API assumes that all of the viewControllers are customizable, and they will all be rearrange-able.

If you don't mind the edit button, but just want some of the views to be rearrange-able, assign an array to tabBar.customizableViewControllers that contains some, but not all, of the full set of viewControllers.

Answer (score 0):

Appdelegate.h

Include

Appdelegate.m

in app delegate.m add add these lines.

include this line in application didfinishlaunchingoptions function;

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    tabBarController.moreNavigationController.delegate = self;
}
```

Add below function in appdelegate.m

```
(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    UINavigationBar *morenavbar = navigationController.navigationBar;
    UINavigationItem *morenavitem = morenavbar.topItem;
    /* We don't need Edit button in More screen. */
    morenavitem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
}
```

thats all , it will work now.

Comment: in appdelegate.h include <UINavigationControllerDelegate>